# Problema con JPanel en Java Swing

Tags: java, java-swing

Hola como estan? soy nuevo en la comunidad. Vengo a consultarles un problema que tengo con Java Swing. La cuestión es, en resumidas cuentas, que tengo un `JFrame` al que le seteo un `JPanel` vacio, algo asi:

```
principal = new JPanel();
getFrm().getContentPane().add(principal);
```

y luego más adelante, me gustaría poder cambiar el contenido de "principal", para lo que hago...

```
principal = new JPanel(); //(1)

principal.add(new JButton("ejemplo");
```

Pero no alcanzo a ver ningun cambio (incluso si llamo a repaint o revalidate). Donde sí veo cambios es si en (1) reemplazo la linea por `principal.removeAll()`

¿Estoy haciendo las cosas bien?
Para dejar en claro me gustaria poder "**vaciar**" todo el contenido de un panel para poder reusarlo en tiempo de ejecución, y mi sentido común me lleva a hacer un "*new*" del panel, pero no funciona.

Comment: eso es porque solo cambias tu referencia a principal, el JPanel sigue teniendo el anterior panel dentro de sus componentes, deberás primero eliminar el panel anterior `getFrm().getContentPane().remove(principal)`, crear el nuevo panel `principal = new JPanel()`  y luego agregar el nuevo panel `getFrm().getContentPane().add(principal)`, posteriormente debes revalidar `this.revalidate()` y pintar nuevamente `this.repaint()`

Comment: Genial! supuse que podia ser un problema de punteros! pero no estaba seguro. Si en lugar de crear un nuevo panel lo reuso haciendo "removeAll()" estaria bien hacerlo? Gracias Eduen!

Comment: En tu caso concreto sí, ya que ahorras el tiempo de crear un nuevo componente (que es bastante), y lo mejor  de todo es que preservarías su posición (en el caso de usar algun layout, preservarías la configuración en el mismo). Si eliminases el componente y lo agregas nuevamente, podrías desordenar tu layout (en caso de usar, si no lo verías hasta abajo de otros)

Comment: Listo, aclarado el problema. Muchisimas gracias amigo!

Comment: De nada y bienvenido a SoEs, agradecería que leyeses [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), si bien la pregunta es objetiva , el título de la pregunta no lo es, saludos.